# Color of 3D trace mesh3d depending on variable value

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to make a 3D scatterplot with plotly on r. The resulting image is monochromatic, while I would like it to change according to the z values, like the output of add_surface.

```
library(plotly)

library(datarium)

plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x = marketing$youtube, y = marketing$facebook, z = marketing$sales, type = "mesh3d")
```

[image: monochromatic mesh3d marketing]

My desired result looks something like this :

```
plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()
```

[image: surface volcano]

Dataset for reproducibility :

```
marketing <- tribble(~youtube, ~facebook, ~sales,
                   270, 45, 26,
                   53, 47, 12,
                   20, 55, 11)
```

Comment: You need a matrix where for example each rowname correspond to `1:length(marketing$youtube)`, each column correspond to `1:length(marketing$facebook)` and each value of each cell corresponds to the corresponding sales value of `[youtube, facebook]`. Then you can plot your matrix with plotly and alternatively, modify the x and y axis labels with youtube and facebook ones

Comment: Thanks Yacine, yes I understood that if my data were a matrix I could use add_surface instead, but I cannot build this matrix. Can you help?

Comment: Yes I can help, could you please launch the output of `dput(marketing)`? Or at least the `head()` of it (in your first question message)

Comment: dataset <- tribble(~youtube, ~facebook, ~sales,
                   270, 45, 26,
                   53, 47, 12,
                   20, 55, 11)

Answer (score 1):

I created another reproducible example because with your dataset there are NA values for a lot of x*y associations.

```
### Import libraries
library(datarium)
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(tibble)

### Data for reproducibility
# markerting dataset (youtube & facebook)
temp <- data.frame(youtube=1:10, 
                   facebook=1:10)
marketing <- expand.grid(temp)

# Adding sales (z) values
set.seed(1)
marketing$sales <- rnorm(100)
```

#### Classic plot_ly for data.frame

```
### Classic plot_ly with data.frame arguments
plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x = marketing$youtube, y = marketing$facebook, z = marketing$sales, type = "mesh3d")
```

[image]

#### Classic volcano plot for matrix

```
### Transforming data.frame into a matrix
marketingForPlotly <- t(acast(marketing, youtube~facebook, value.var="sales"))

### Volcano plot_ly with matrix arguments
plot_ly(z = ~marketingForPlotly) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your example, but this approach (with add_surface) doesn't work with many datasets for which matrix transformation causes lots of NAs, as you said. I stll wonder whether mesh3d can be coloured according to variable z